# How to get reference clip to start in middle of timeline?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

Cycles Render Vers- 2.79

I need to use a reference clip for the final action of my animation, but that action starts at frame 720, and the reference clip ends at frame 300. How do i get the reference clip to start at a desired key frame on the timeline?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If I understand the question, you've got a set of animation keyframes for the model in the dopesheet already at frame 1?  If so is there any reason you can't simply slide them as a whole, up to frame 720?

Comment: I dont know if that would solve my issue, if im understanding you. I would have to figure out how to get my reference animation to start at frame 1440, then. The reference clip  and animations would start at frame 720 instead of frame 1.

Comment: Er - frame 1440? Like 720 x 2?

Comment: Tell me, is the ref clip in the Action Editor or NLA by any chance?

Comment: Im sorry im still very new at this. What is NLA? 

The reference clip is in the background images

Comment: I know how you feel! (lol)  Are the keyframes actually in the Dopesheet and at frame 1?

Comment: Oh yes, the keyframes are in the dope sheet and at frame 1. I need the reference clip im using in background images to start at frame 720.

Comment: I see there are highlited keyframes and non-highlited.  Are the highlited ones the ref clip you want to move?

Comment: hmmmm... i dont know, to be honest. Give me a second to mess with stuff and find out, thank you.

Comment: Dang... No the unhighlighted key frames were not the clip. Just unhighlighted.

Comment: Basically, all that's needed (fingers crossed) is to press 'A' to clear the highlites, then  'B'  (for box select) and drag the box to ONLY include the keyframes you want.  Once the mouse button is released, Press key G (for grab) and move the mouse without buttons pressed to the right.  The highlited keyframes will move also.  Take the leftmost keyframe(s) up to the frame number you wish to start at.

Comment: A useful hint - at the bottom of the Dopesheet, you'll see a ghost icon, click on that and the arrow icon next to it to declutter the DopeSheet.  Only the object(s) selected will appear in the Dopesheet.

Comment: Does the reference clip located in the background images show up in the dope sheet? I thought the dope sheet shows animation key frames? i dont need to move the animation i already have made, i need to start the externally sourced reference clip located in the background images at frame 720. the only keyframes in the dope sheet i can find are movements i made to the model and not the reference clip im using to make the animation.

Comment: Apologies - I was seeing the ref clip as animation clips.  For an image that's a lot easier.  I'm using vers 2.77a here so 2.79 might be a little different.  Here goes - Go to the texture properties for your background plane and open the image tab. Down at the bottom of that section are boxes that - hang on a sec...

Comment: ...to continue - a box called "Auto refresh"  Tick that to make the anim move.  At the left of that is another pair - "start & offset."   The "START" slot is the frame number you want the clip to start from in Blender's timeline.  The Offset moves the starting frame IN the CLIP itself to somewhere after the beginning of the clip.  Sorry for the confusion. You showed all those keyframes and I took it to mean you needed to shift those.  (I call keyframes ref clips that can be imported into other projects)

Comment: ohhh i see. Sorry about the confusion. I should have used the term "movie clip" as thats how its titled in blender. 

Thank you so much

Comment: Your welcome - have you tried it yet?

Comment: I am working on finding everything. Maybe .77 is a little more different than .79. Im trying to find the texture properties for the background plane.

Comment: Not a problem.  I'll head off for a bite to eat (Australian time) and look in in a half hour...  If anyone's watching and familiar with 2.79 we could use some help. :)   BTW you have to select your model, then at the extreme right are the properties panels.   You click on the Material tab first, then the texture, a coloured checkerboard of sorts.

Comment: Back again - After no less than 20 comments/exchanges, I think an answer post would be in order if only to clearly set out the process.  I'll place one up now and if it's not the answer for you, drop another comment at the answer itself and I'll delete it.  Happy Blending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texturing a plane with a video/image- For a Background Image see Edit below...

I'm using vers 2.77a here so 2.79 might be a little different. Here goes -

Select your model first in the 3D window.

At the extreme right are the 'Properties panels'.  The one with a small brown sphere is the "Material properties panel"  Click on that.

Go to the Texture properties next.  That's shown as a tiny coloured checkerboard of 
sorts.  Click on that.

Go down to the "Image" tab and open that.

Down near the bottom is a tick-box called "Auto Refresh".  Make sure that's ticked to 
make the video play.

At the left of that is a pair of slots - "Start & Offset".

Click in the "Start slot and enter the Blender timeline frame-number that you want the video to commence playing from.

The Offset slot points to the frame number within the video-clip itself that it's to treat as it's first frame.  (like pulling a tape or film strip through a player and starting from there)

---

EDIT 27th April 2019 - re Movie clip as a Background Image -

The same applies in the bkd image's panel.

Press N to open up the Viewport's properties. Scroll down to the "Background Image" tab and open that.  Click on the image folder icon to open your movie.

In there you'll see the same tick-boxes and entry slots as mentioned above.

You'll notice the "Opacity" slider is set at half by default.  Wind it up to 100% for full opacity.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to finish my animation, thanks to your help.

Comment: That's good news.  In the interim and away from the computer it dawned on me that you were using a background image, not texturing a plane as I guessed when looking at your pics. (appearing to be subdivided planes and actors texturing those.  Fortunately the same tick boxes would be in the Bkd Image panel so I guess you would have found those ok.  You got there, that's the main thing.  I was wondering, do you think we should delete all 'dem comments above?  They'd sure make a good comedy script!  lol  Exercise in communication!

Comment: Thanks @Leander, you're quick!  I can see that in your link, trying to figure out how to bring it up.  Will go back into Edit mode and see what I can find. -- Back again but cannot see anything re 'Side by side'.

Comment: @Leander , Found what you referring to.  I'm a little puzzled. The two texts need a divider line for sure.  I'll read up a Stack Exchange link I saved yonks ago, re formatting. Can't see anything like that in the shortcuts at the top of the edit box.

Comment: Sorted it out @Leander.  My eyes are nowhere near what they used to be and I use the Windows' black screen with yellow text, high contrast so I can read what's there.  Your edit even with side by side didn't show.  I've added a ruler line but it's so faint when viewed with the normal Windows setup, it's all but invisible, to my peepers at least.   A short divider as I've been using draws attention to the division and doesn't go right across so it doesn't appear to be a separate answer.  So, I can't use that style anymore?

Comment: I just though you didn't know about the thin line divider. I can see it fine in different setups. If you think it is too faint, use whatever divider you want.

Comment: Thanks @Leander.  The quarter line is visible in all setups and emphasizes the division.  This is often necessary to direct a reader's attention to the (sub)division and separate the context of what's between them and the main body that surrounds it.  Thanks for your interest though.